# Parse JavaScript with jsoup

Tags: javascript, java, html, kotlin, jsoup

In an `HTML` page, I want to pick the value of a `javascript` variable.
Below is the snippet of `HTML` page:

```
<input id="hidval" value="" type="hidden"> 
<form method="post" style="padding: 0px;margin: 0px;" name="profile" autocomplete="off">
<input name="pqRjnA" id="pqRjnA" value="" type="hidden">
<script type="text/javascript">
    key="pqRjnA";
</script>
```

My aim is to read the value of variable `key` from this page using `jsoup`.
Is it possible with `jsoup`? If yes then how?

Comment: You'd have to get the script content then either parse manually, or see if you could use Rhino to get context out of an executed JS fragment.

Comment: @Reimeus: no. Initialization can be done somewhere else here some value is being assigned to variable `key`.

Comment: Added *kotlin* tag because a [similar Koltlin question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65007018/8583692) is marked duplicate and is linked to this question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since jsoup isn't a javascript library you have two ways to solve this:

### A. Use a javascript library

- **Pro:**

  - Full Javascript support
- **Con:**

  - Additional libraray / dependencies

### B. Use Jsoup + manual parsing

- **Pro:**

  - No extra libraries required
  - Enough for simple tasks
- **Con:**

  - Not as flexible as a javascript library

Here's an example how to get the `key` with jsoupand some *"manual"* code:

```
Document doc = ...
Element script = doc.select("script").first(); // Get the script part


Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?is)key=\"(.+?)\""); // Regex for the value of the key
Matcher m = p.matcher(script.html()); // you have to use html here and NOT text! Text will drop the 'key' part


while( m.find() )
{
    System.out.println(m.group()); // the whole key ('key = value')
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // value only
}
```

**Output (using your html part):**

```
key="pqRjnA"
pqRjnA
```

Comment: Hey, `Jsoup + manual parsing` is very good solution for this, but breaking while I am using the js variable as array. `eg: keyArray = [1, 2, 3]` can you please give me solution for this.

Comment: You can use this regex instead: `(?s)(keyArray)\\s??=\\s??\\[(.*?)\\]`. If defined two groups: Group 1 = variable name, group 2 = value (those within `[ ]`).

Comment: And What if I have something like `abc.xyz.init({requiredJsonObjectAsAnArgument});` inside script tags and I want to parse requiredJsonObjectAsAnArgument only. Can you suggest me the applicable regex for this case?

Comment: Please try `(?s)\\.init\\(\\{(.+?)\\}\\);` - group #1 contains the `requiredJsonObjectAsAnArgument`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Kotlin question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65007018/8583692) is marked as duplicate and is directed to this question.
So, here is how I did that with Kotlin:

```kotlin
val (key, value) = document
    .select("script")
    .map(Element::data)
    .first { "key" in it } // OR single { "key" in it }
    .split("=")
    .map(String::trim)
val pureValue = value.replace(Regex("""["';]"""), "")
println("$key::$pureValue") // key::pqRjnA
```

Another version:

```kotlin
val (key, value) = document
    .select("script")
    .first { Regex("""key\s*=\s*["'].*["'];""") in it.data() }
    .data()
    .split("=")
    .map { it.replace(Regex("""[\s"';]"""), "") }
println("$key::$value") // key::pqRjnA
```

##### Footnote

To get the document you can do this:

- From a file:

  ```kotlin
  val input = File("my-document.html")
  val document = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8")
  ```
- From a server:

  ```kotlin
  val document = Jsoup.connect("the/target/url")
      .userAgent("Mozilla")
      .get()
  ```