# How to get the text within a <span> tag knowing its ID with java and jsoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

im tring to get the text within a  tag. I know its id, which is "lblCompra" and "lblVenta".

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bccr.fi.cr//").get();
    Element compra = doc.getElementById("lblCompra");
    Element venta = doc.getElementById("lblVenta");   
    System.out.println(compra);
    System.out.println(venta);
```

But what i get is bunch of text I dont need. Here's the output:

```
<span id="lblCompra"> <img src="images/waiting.gif" alt="cargando" /> </span>
<span id="lblVenta"> <img src="images/waiting.gif" alt="cargando" /> </span>
```

what i should be getting is like "400.0" and "450.0" or something like that.

Comment: Why do you expect gettig 400 or 450 whereas there is an image within the span tag?

Comment: what are u getting from this url http://www.bccr.fi.cr/ ?

Comment: the actual HTML code of the website states
 '<span id="lblCompra">493,51</span>' but i get the gif image. idk :s

Comment: @anulik im trying to get the first 2 numbers the mid right panel. below "tipo de cambio y taza"

Comment: i think that the point is in that webpage that inforamtion is loading via AJAX, that is why you are getting this image http://www.bccr.fi.cr/images/waiting.gif  , and if the content is coming with AJAX, it's can't be seen cause in SEO also, AJAX contexts are not longer indexed,  I THINK SO

Answer (score 2):

In order to get text value of an element try using [text()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text%28%29) method:

`System.out.println(compra.text());`

UPDATE: the value you are looking for is loaded by JavaScript.
Consult this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904776/parse-javascript-with-jsoup)

Comment: I tried that but it returns a white space. I guess that since the return value is a gif image within a span class (IDK why because  the actual HTML line states <span id="lblCompra">493,51</span> ) getting the text of that is nonesense, beacuse there's is no text. i think im getting the wrong element

Comment: Why do you put a hashtag before ID in `Element compra = doc.getElementById("#lblCompra");`? Did you try just `getElementById("lblCompra")`?

Comment: yeah, that was my mistake. and yes I already tried that but I'm still getting a gif image instead of some text :s

Comment: OK @Limbo you were right. i found the freaking gif image under that ID haha. Do you know how can I state that they are the children of a DIV class"myclass" for example?

Comment: In fact the problem is the value you need is not in the source of the page, it is probably loaded by Javascript, so jsoup doesn't see 493.51 in the source. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904776/parse-javascript-with-jsoup

Answer (score 0):

if you use getElementById() ...you will get the element. Now that you have the element get the value from the element. Use the getValue() method to get the value

Comment: i couldnt find that method. I found one .data() but stil. i think my mistake is returning the right element but i dont know why :/

Comment: Since you are newbie to java make sure that you have the right element class imported. The Element class should be of org.jdom package

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `doc.getElementById("#lblCompra").innerHTML` will work?

Or if you want to get width and height of img, you can do this:

```
doc.getElementById('#lblCompra').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].width;
```

Comment: how can i use jquery? please note that im using netbeans and i am a newbie in java

Comment: oh, i tought u r using JSP

Comment: then maybe doc.getElementById("#lblCompra").innerHTML will work?

Comment: i am sorry, but one more thing i don't understand,you are mentioning "im tring to get the text within a tag" but you have put img in your span, wich text do u talking about?

Comment: yes, that's right. the html states "<span id="lblCompra">493,51</span>" but im getting a gif image and i dont know why :s

Comment: maybe the point is in your url ? what are you tying to get from that url?

Comment: i found my mistake. there's a gif image with the "lblCompra" id too! the one i want is contained in a div class "exampleClass". Do you know how to retrieve the "lblCompra" text i want? (: