# JSoup and Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, regex, parsing, jsoup

I have a Javascript in my HTML code. I want navigate through the links ending with "Doc". In this HTML there is only one link, called SunnydataDoc. So I want search this string on this page and if there are existing any links ending with "Doc", I want to navigate further down in those pages. 
Could you please help me out in this? I've heard I can use regex and match methods in combination with Jsoup.
Here my code.

```
<script>
    var data = {"totalRecords": 2, "sort": "name", "startIndex": 0, "dir": "asc", "records": [{"raw_name": "samia/export/sunnydata", "last_changeset": "\n  <div>\n      <pre><a title=\"ownerID:\n\nAdded tag V2.11.d50.mkt.001 for changeset 56e10a4864ff\" class=\"tooltip\" href=\"/samia/export/sunnydata/changeset/f602409eba261d749d23dc75551b2959425dfa8d\">r17:f602409eba26</a></pre>\n  </div>\n", "atom": "\n    <a title=\"Subscribe to samia/export/sunnydata atom feed\" href=\"/samia/export/sunnydata/feed/atom?api_key=e214ebea2335318bee1460a1fd33725ab3e1002e\"><i class=\"icon-rss-sign\"  style=\"color: #fa9b39\"></i></a>\n", "owner": "ownerID (Owner)", "rss": "\n    <a title=\"Subscribe to samia/export/sunnydata rss feed\" href=\"/samia/export/sunnydata/feed/rss?api_key=e214ebea2335318bee1460a1fd33725ab3e1002e\"><i class=\"icon-rss-sign\" style=\"color: #fa9b39\"></i></a>\n", "name": "\n    \n  <div style=\"white-space: nowrap; }\">\n        <a href=\"/samia/export/sunnydata\">\n\n        <span title=\"Mercurial repository\"><i class=\"icon-hg\" style=\"color: #316293; font-size: 14px;\"></i></span>\n\n      <span style=\"margin: 0px 8px 0px 8px\"></span>\n    Sunnydata\n    </a>\n  </div>\n", "last_rev_raw": 17, "state": "\n  <div>\n        <div class=\"btn btn-mini btn-success disabled\">Created</div>\n  </div>\n", "menu": "\n  <ul class=\"menu_items hidden\">\n\n    <li style=\"border-top:1px solid #003367;margin-left:18px;padding-left:-99px\"></li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Summary\" href=\"/samia/export/sunnydata\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-file-text\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Summary</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Changelog\" href=\"/samia/export/sunnydata/changelog\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-list-alt\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Changelog</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Files\" href=\"/samia/export/sunnydata/files/tip/\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-file-alt\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Files</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Fork\" href=\"/samia/export/sunnydata/fork\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-code-fork\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Fork</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n  </ul>\n", "desc": "GHU Sunnydataimport", "last_change": "\n  <span class=\"tooltip\" date=\"2014-08-21 18:49:50\" title=\"Thu, 21 Aug 2014 18:49:50\">10 days and 16 hours ago</span>\n"}, {"raw_name": "samia/export/sunnydatadoc", "last_changeset": "\n  <div>\n      <pre><a title=\"ownerID;lt;owneremail;gt;:\n\nChangedokumentation\" class=\"tooltip\" href=\"/samia/export/sunnydataDoc/changeset/9ed1679c7a35b76e1402b540cee38000461fdfdd\">r0:9ed1679c7a35</a></pre>\n  </div>\n", "atom": "\n    <a title=\"Subscribe to samia/export/sunnydataDoc atom feed\" href=\"/samia/export/sunnydataDoc/feed/atom?api_key=e214ebea2335318bee1460a1fd33725ab3e1002e\"><i class=\"icon-rss-sign\"  style=\"color: #fa9b39\"></i></a>\n", "owner": "ownerID (Owner)", "rss": "\n    <a title=\"Subscribe to samia/export/sunnydataDoc rss feed\" href=\"/samia/export/sunnydataDoc/feed/rss?api_key=e214ebea2335318bee1460a1fd33725ab3e1002e\"><i class=\"icon-rss-sign\" style=\"color: #fa9b39\"></i></a>\n", "name": "\n    \n  <div style=\"white-space: nowrap; }\">\n        <a href=\"/samia/export/sunnydataDoc\">\n\n        <span title=\"Mercurial repository\"><i class=\"icon-hg\" style=\"color: #316293; font-size: 14px;\"></i></span>\n\n      <span style=\"margin: 0px 8px 0px 8px\"></span>\n    SunnydataDoc\n    </a>\n  </div>\n", "last_rev_raw": 0, "state": "\n  <div>\n        <div class=\"btn btn-mini btn-success disabled\">Created</div>\n  </div>\n", "menu": "\n  <ul class=\"menu_items hidden\">\n\n    <li style=\"border-top:1px solid #003367;margin-left:18px;padding-left:-99px\"></li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Summary\" href=\"/samia/export/sunnydataDoc\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-file-text\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Summary</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Changelog\" href=\"/samia/export/sunnydataDoc/changelog\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-list-alt\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Changelog</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Files\" href=\"/samia/export/sunnydataDoc/files/tip/\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-file-alt\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Files</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Fork\" href=\"/samia/export/sunnydataDoc/fork\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-code-fork\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Fork</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n  </ul>\n", "desc": "GHU Sunnydataimport (Dokumentation)", "last_change": "\n  <span class=\"tooltip\" date=\"2014-04-25 11:03:45\" title=\"Fri, 25 Apr 2014 11:03:45\">4 months and 6 days ago</span>\n"}]};
    var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource(data);
    myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSON;
```

So in this example I have this link: href=\"/samia/export/sunnydataDoc\". I want to take this link and go in there with my code.

And this is my Java code.

```
public class JScripttest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Response res = Jsoup
            .connect(
                    "url")
            .data("username", "username", "password", "password")
            .method(Method.POST).execute();
    Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url")
            .cookies(loginCookies).get();


    Element script = doc.select("href").last();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("href\s=\s"([^"]+Doc)""); // Regex for the value of the href
    Matcher m = p.matcher(script.html()); // you have to use html here and NOT text! Text will drop the 'href' part

    while( m.find() )
    {
        System.out.println(m.group()); 
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }

    }



private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
    System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
}
```

So I get errors in "Pattern...."line

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

This regex gets you the links that end in `Doc`. I'm unsure what you mean with "go in" but this should help you on your way. Group 1 contains the URL.

```
href\s*=\s*"([^"]+Doc)"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/F9dsw-6xLBqxaT0E)

Properly escaped `"` in Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("href\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]+Doc)\"");
```

Comment: I am using the pattern and matcher for this. So is that correct? I get errors.
`  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(href\s*=\s*"([^"]+Doc)"); Matcher m = p.matcher(script.html());

Comment: You seem to be confusing Java and JavaScript. Despite the unfortunate similarity in name, they have little to do with each other. Your `<script>` tag makes me think you're working with JavaScript on a website, but `Pattern p = Pattern.compile()` is Java. Take a look here for help with regexes in JavaScript: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: No I am not confusing. I program with Jsoup which is Java and having the Javascript code in the HTML code, where I parse and fetch with Jsoup. I take an example of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904776/parse-javascript-with-jsoup and wanted to build your approach in my code.

Comment: Ah, that explains. Could you update your question with the Java code you have? It looks like you forgot tot put the regex in `"` and escape the `"` inside the regex, you can see in the link you gave, take a good look at where `"` and `\"` is placed: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?is)key=\"(.+?)\"");`

Comment: updated. To your question with "go in", I mean I want to go inside of that "href=http:/..../...Doc" link and do more things.

Comment: I edited my answer with proper Java escaping. every `"` **inside** the regex must have a `\` in front of it just like the answer of the question your linked to. Please try and read more carefully and you would've seen the the `\`s yourself I'm sure. It is also generally not appreciated that you comment something like _any suggestions?_ as it is seen as impatient.

Comment: Hi,
sorry your updated answer is also not working, I am getting error Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ ).

Comment: Ah yes, `\s` needs to be double escaped, changed.

Comment: Could something be wrong with "href\\s=\\s\"([^\"]+Doc)\""? I run the code and it comes back with "No match found" in the console. Does it mean it couldnt find the links ending with "Doc" or something else. The url I am targeting is having definetely the "Doc"-href links. I can sysout the script html and can see the "Doc" links.

Comment: Hi @funkwurm,
so I dont shout here again, "Any suggestions" :-)
I ask politely, to whom it is interesting, Can anyone help, please.
The regex doesnt come up with error now, but I receive "no match found" in the console. So somekind of a lost in the ocean.

Comment: In your comment of yesterday you've omitted the `*` after `\\s`, might this be the issue?