# Parse a singlepage web application

Tags: java, angularjs, parsing, jsoup, single-page-application

Is there any library for java to parse singlepage web sites, for example those created using AngularJs?

It seems from official docs for jsoup, that it doesn't work with js.

The solution shouldn't use any installed browser.

Comment: Try [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net), which has JS support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JonasCz mentioned, try to use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

A code could look like:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
        HtmlPage page = null;
        try {
            page = webClient.getPage("https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http");
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        System.out.println(page.asXml());
        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's proper code to download page using AngularJS with HtmlUnit

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);

webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());

webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(true);
webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(true);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);

try {
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(URL);
    System.out.println(page.asText());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
webClient.closeAllWindows();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following link, it might solve your problem.

[try jsoup + manual parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904776/parse-javascript-with-jsoup)

Comment: Thanks, but I need js to be executed (js could dramatically change the html code).