# How a get a variable value from HTML using Java Code?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsoup

I made a HttpClient call to a server and it responded with a response of HTML. In which I see something like

```
 <html lang="en"><head>
 <script type="text/javascript"><!--
  var testElement = "Y4Yyn%2bZXWcmpz2TadkTlyrc8yGI%3d";   var timeout_redirect_url = "/career?company=asd&loginFlowRequired=true&lang=en_US";
 //--></script>
 </html>
```

I have saved all the HTML content to a String.

Now I have all the HTML in

```
String res;
```

res contains all the HTML.

I need to get that `testElement` value. The response which I got is a string. How can I get the `testElement` value?

I'm trying to parse for jsoup to get the value but got struck. Can anyone help me out please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The big problem here is that you want data, but get a html string back instead. If you have no way to get the data in non-html format, you're stuck with either searching the string for the text describing the variable and splice out the corrent part, (everything between var testElement = " and the closing ") which is quite error prone. Or you could create a new document, insert the html string into it and then insert another script tag  that will expose the local variable testElement. (which can be complicated.)

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904776/parse-javascript-with-jsoup

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to accomplish this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "<html lang=\"en\"><head>" +
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\"><!--" +
    "var testElement = \"Y4Yyn%2bZXWcmpz2TadkTlyrc8yGI%3d\";   var timeout_redirect_url = \"/career?company=asd&loginFlowRequired=true&lang=en_US\";"+
    "//--></script>"+
    "</html>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=testElement\\s=\\s\").*?(?=\")");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
    while(matcher.find())
    {
        String s = matcher.group(0);
        System.out.println("" + s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Y4Yyn%2bZXWcmpz2TadkTlyrc8yGI%3d
```

Try it out hopefully that is what you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks. I have used split method and got the required output.

Answer (score 0):

Actually whatever value you are getting in testElement  variable I guess is a object, you need to get back the elements within it and parse it to get the expected output.

Comment: It is not the Object. I think it is a String. If it is a String do you know how to get that value?

Comment: Please provide more information, this is not adequate to answer your query.