# Can not extract the elements i want from html by jsoup

Tags: javascript, html, jsoup

Page is here
http://www.yildiz.edu.tr/etkinlikler/

Source of it:
view-source:http://www.yildiz.edu.tr/etkinlikler/

I did not want to put screenshots because it is really long. I would have to put a lot of screenshots.

I want to take this

```
title: 'ss Event',
start: new Date(y, m, 1)
```

Not all, only after title and date.

But there seems no class or another header for it, because it is in javascript class:

```
 </div>
    </div>
</div>


</div>    </div>
</div>    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: false,
        events: [
                    {
                title: 'birthday party',
                start: new Date(2015, 9, 26),
                                    end: new Date(2015, 10, 13),
                                    url: 'http://www.yildiz.edu.tr/etkinlikler/Uygarlıkların Geçiş Yolu  &  Anadolu Peyzajı/237'

            },


{
                title: 'Concert',
                start: new Date(2015, 5, 12),
                                    end: new Date(2015, 5, 19),
                                    url: 'http://www.yildiz.edu.tr/etkinlikler/İki Seçki İki Salon İki Sergi/233'

            },

                        ]
    });

});

</script>

    <style type='text/css'>
        #calendar {
            width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            }

</style>
```

I tried

```
Elements event = document.select("#events");
```

but it did not work.Should i use another tool?

Comment: Is there a reason this part of the code is commented ?

Comment: Yes, to show past events. I edited again, I wont take the events inside comment.

Comment: it seems the event title 'ss Event' is commented . Is this on purpose ?

Comment: [`select("#id")`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) will return HTML Elements, not a javascript hash member. There is no element on that page with `id='events'`.

Comment: I changed the code. IT is showing also past evnts, comment line finishes after to date events start. Near dates events are not in comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14925848/3575963 i try to use this but inside there is function,not such members. So only way seems regex after i take inside script?But in the page there are more script columns. I dont know how to choose this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.yildiz.edu.tr/etkinlikler/").get();
String script = doc.select("script").get(10).toString();
String pattern = "\\{\\s*title\\s*:\\s*(.*),\\s*start\\s*:\\s*(.*),\\s*end.*";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(script);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " -> " + m.group(2));
}
```

The output:

```
'Long Event' -> new Date(y, m, d-5)
'Lunch' -> new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0)
'Birthday Party' -> new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0)
'Kemal Gök Fotoğraf Sergisi :Kentleşme Sürecinde Çocuk İşçiler' -> new Date(2015, 10, 17)
'Uygarlıkların Geçiş Yolu  &  Anadolu Peyzajı' -> new Date(2015, 9, 26)
'Vizöre Çarpanlar' -> new Date(2015, 8, 9)
'İki Seçki İki Salon İki Sergi' -> new Date(2015, 5, 12)
```

Comment: Yes that is it :) And is there a way to get the events dates after comment lines?

Comment: you can remove comment characters by String.replace after use regex

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something else. Jsoup will not let you work with Javascript, only the HTML parse tree.

At maximum, you can get the whole script text using document.select("script").get(1).toString().

Once you get the script text, you may consider other options such as regex, or maybe some Javascript parsing tool that does what you require.