# Searching for keyworkd in webpage

Tags: javascript, java

I have wrriten some code for searching specific word in some webpage.
But, I have some problem, it finds all the keyword, excpet that in the javascript part of the webpage.
I dont know javasrcipt, Only java :|
Somebody can help me?
Thanks.

This is my code -

```
String searchWord = "WORD";
    String url = "SOME URL";

    Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(USER_AGENT);
    System.out.println("Searching for the word " + searchWord);
    Document htmlDocument = connection.get();

    if(htmlDocument.body().text() != null){
                if((htmlDocument.body().text()).toLowerCase().contains(searchWord.toLowerCase()))
                    System.out.println("yes");
                else
                    System.out.println("No");

                                            }
```

Im using the Jsoup jar.

Comment: This code code seems to be Java, so your lack of knowledge of JavaScript is irrelevant. It also seems to check the `<body>` element of the webpage. Is your Javascript contained inside the body? (If so, that would be fairly unusual. If not, there's your problem.)

Comment: The javascript part is in the <body> element of the webpage. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Read your ***js*** file and process it as below (*Java SE 7*):

```
    Path source = Paths.get("sourcecode.js");   

    Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");

    try(BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(source, charset)) {
        String line;
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
            if((line).toLowerCase().contains(searchWord.toLowerCase()))
                System.out.println("yes");
            else
                System.out.println("No");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JSoup is not meant for parsing JavaScript, it is intended for HTML.

[Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) is a better option and provides a 'javax.script' variable for parsing Javascript.

If you must use JSoup, then you will need to manually parse the '' node, using a regular expression and parsing the HTML and not as text, see this link for more information on manually parsing the Javascript using JSoup:

[Parse JavaScript with jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904776/parse-javascript-with-jsoup)