# href field missing when I get the page using jsoup or htmlunit

Tags: javascript, java, parsing, jsoup, htmlunit

I'm trying to parse [google images search result](https://www.google.de/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=955&q=naruto%20shippuden&gws_rd=cr).

I'm trying to get the **href attribute** of an element. I've noticed that the **href field** is missing when I get the page programmatically (this happens with both jsoup and htmlunit).
Comparing the element of the page got programmatically through java and the element of the page loaded by the actual browser, the only difference is, indeed, the **href field** that is missing (the rest is the same).

The href attribute (IMAGE_LINK) is the following: `/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.zonarutoppuden.com%2Fns%2Fpe‌​liculas-naruto-shipp‌​uden.jpg&imgrefurl=h‌​ttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.zona‌​rutoppuden.com%2F201‌​0%2F10%2Fnaruto-ship‌​puden-peliculas.html‌​&docid=JR8NPqKrF3ac_‌​M&tbnid=0EPPOYQcflXk‌​MM%3A&w=900&h=600&bi‌​h=638&biw=1275&ved=0‌​ahUKEwih9O2e88_OAhWM‌​ExoKHRLGAGQQMwg2KAMw‌​Aw&iact=mrc&uact=8`

Maybe some issue with the javascript engine? Or maybe some kind of algorithm anti-parsing used by the website?

Snippet Java Code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(50000);
HtmlPage page1=null;

        try {
            // Get the first page
            page1 = webClient.getPage(URL);
            System.out.println(page1.asXml());
        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Snippet Html Code (Real Browser):

```
<a jsaction="fire.ivg_o;mouseover:str.hmov;mouseout:str.hmou" class="rg_l" style="width: 134px; height: 201px; left: 0px; background: rgb(128, 128, 128);" href="IMAGE_LINK"> CONTENT... </a>
```

Snippet Html Code (Page got programmatically):

```
<a jsaction="fire.ivg_o;mouseover:str.hmov;mouseout:str.hmou" class="rg_l" style="width: 134px; height: 201px; left: 0px; background: rgb(128, 128, 128);"> CONTENT... </a>
```

Thank you.

Comment: `In case you need a code snippet let me know.` Yes, please!

Comment: @ppeterka, I've updated the question!

Comment: Maybe the website uses javascript to set `href` attributes.

Comment: @DavidePastore, yeah, I believe so. But htmlunit has JavaScript Engine. Well, the javascript engine of htmlunit it's a litte bugged.

Comment: [Jsoup DOESN'T have a JavaScript Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14925848/1992780).

Comment: Either give us a real link or remove the question: in it's current state needed information is missing, so we can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @F.Klein, sure! 
I'm trying to parse google images search result.
The href attribute (IMAGE_LINK) is the following:

/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.zonarutoppuden.com%2Fns%2Fpeliculas-naruto-shippuden.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zonarutoppuden.com%2F2010%2F10%2Fnaruto-shippuden-peliculas.html&docid=JR8NPqKrF3ac_M&tbnid=0EPPOYQcflXkMM%3A&w=900&h=600&bih=638&biw=1275&ved=0ahUKEwih9O2e88_OAhWMExoKHRLGAGQQMwg2KAMwAw&iact=mrc&uact=8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each search result there is a `<div class="rg_meta">`containing a JSON object, which also holds the url. Using a JSON parser like [json-simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) to parse the object, the following code prints the image urls:

```
String searchTerm = "naruto shippuden";
String searchUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=955&q=" + searchTerm.replace(" ", "+") + "&gws_rd=cr";

try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(searchUrl)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36")
            .referrer("https://www.google.com/").get();

    JSONObject obj;

    for (Element result : doc.select("div.rg_meta")) {

        // div.rg_meta contains a JSON object, which also holds the image url
        obj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(result.text());

        String imageUrl = (String) obj.get("ou");

        // just printing out the url to demonstate the approach
        System.out.println("imageUrl: " + imageUrl);    
    } 

} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
imageUrl: http://ib3.huluim.com/show_key_art/1603?size=1600x600&region=US
imageUrl: http://cdn.zonarutoppuden.com/ns/peliculas-naruto-shippuden.jpg
imageUrl: http://www.saiyanisland.com/news/wp-content/uploads2/2014/12/Naruto-Sasuke.jpg
...
```

**Update**

Since jsAction doesn't seem to play nicely with htmlUnit, I would propose to use [phantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/). Just [download the binary](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) for your OS and create a script file.

create a `page.js` file:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';

page.zoomFactor = 0.1;

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1920,
  height: 1080
};

var divCount="-1";
var topPosition=0;
var unchangedCounter=0;

page.open('https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&q=naruto+shippuden&gws_rd=cr', function(status) {
    console.log("Status: " + status);
    if(status === "success") {

        window.setInterval(function() {

            var newDivCount = page.evaluate(function() { 
                var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".rg_di.rg_bx.rg_el.ivg-i");
                return divs[divs.length-1].getAttribute("data-ri");
            });

            topPosition = topPosition + 1080;

            page.scrollPosition = {
                top: topPosition,
                left: 0
            };

            if(newDivCount===divCount){
                page.evaluate(function() {
                    var button = document.querySelector("#smb");
                    console.log("buttontype:"+typeof button);
                    if(!(typeof button === "undefined")) {
                        button.click();
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                if(unchangedCounter===5){
                    console.log(newDivCount);
                    var path = 'output.html';
                    fs.write(path, page.content, 'w');
                    phantom.exit();
                }else{
                    unchangedCounter=unchangedCounter+1;
                }
            }else{
                unchangedCounter=0;
            }
            divCount = newDivCount;

        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Now we execute the script file with phantomJs and parse the result as before with jsoup:

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bin\\phantomjs page.js"); //change path to phantomjs binary and your script file
    process.waitFor();

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("output.html"),"UTF-8"); // output.html is created by phantom.js, same path as page.js

    for (Element element : doc.select("div.rg_di.rg_bx.rg_el.ivg-i a")) {
        System.out.println(element.attr("href"));
    }
    System.out.println("Number of results: " + doc.select("div.rg_di.rg_bx.rg_el.ivg-i a").size());
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fib3.huluim.com%2Fshow_key_art%2F1603%3Fsize%3D1600x600%26region%3DUS&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hulu.com%2Fnaruto-shippuden&docid=OgW4j66rp7CKkM&tbnid=SElXvYDJj9cR6M%3A&w=1600&h=600&bih=10800&biw=19200&ved=0ahUKEwjX2PXmptPOAhULVxoKHXfmDg8QMwgzKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8
/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.zonarutoppuden.com%2Fns%2Fpeliculas-naruto-shippuden.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zonarutoppuden.com%2F2010%2F10%2Fnaruto-shippuden-peliculas.html&docid=JR8NPqKrF3ac_M&tbnid=0EPPOYQcflXkMM%3A&w=900&h=600&bih=10800&biw=19200&ved=0ahUKEwjX2PXmptPOAhULVxoKHXfmDg8QMwg0KAEwAQ&iact=mrc&uact=8
...
Number of results: 463
```

**Update: passing the url as a parameter to the script**

**Script** `page.js`

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var system = require('system');

var url = "";
var searchParameter = "";

if (system.args.length === 3) {
    url=system.args[1];
    searchParameter=system.args[2];
}

if(url==="" || searchParameter===""){
    phantom.exit();
}

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';

page.zoomFactor = 0.1;

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1920,
  height: 1080
};

var divCount="-1";
var topPosition=0;
var unchangedCounter=0;

page.open(url, function(status) {
    console.log("Status: " + status);
    if(status === "success") {

        window.setInterval(function() {

            var newDivCount = page.evaluate(function() { 
                var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".rg_di.rg_bx.rg_el.ivg-i");
                return divs[divs.length-1].getAttribute("data-ri");
            });

            topPosition = topPosition + 1080;

            page.scrollPosition = {
                top: topPosition,
                left: 0
            };

            if(newDivCount===divCount){
                page.evaluate(function() {
                    var button = document.querySelector("#smb");
                    if(!(typeof button === "undefined")) {
                        button.click();
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                if(unchangedCounter===5){
                    var path = searchParameter+'.html';
                    fs.write(path, page.content, 'w');
                    phantom.exit();
                }else{
                    unchangedCounter=unchangedCounter+1;
                }
            }else{
                unchangedCounter=0;
            }
            divCount = newDivCount;

        }, 500);
    }else{
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

**Java code**

```
try {
    //change path to phantomjs binary and your script file
    String phantomJSPath = "phantomjs" + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "phantomjs";
    String scriptFile = "page.js";

    String searchTerm = "naruto+shippuden";
    String urlParameter = "https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&gws_rd=cr&q="+searchTerm;

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(phantomJSPath + " " + scriptFile + " " + urlParameter + " " + searchTerm);
    process.waitFor();

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File(searchTerm + ".html"),"UTF-8"); // output.html is created by phantom.js, same path as page.js

    for (Element element : doc.select("div.rg_di.rg_bx.rg_el.ivg-i a")) {
        System.out.println(element.attr("href"));
    }
    System.out.println("Number of results: " + doc.select("div.rg_di.rg_bx.rg_el.ivg-i a").size());
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Worked just fine, thank you! I didn't notice at all that **<div class="rg_meta">** was containing  the url.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept it as answer and upvote. Cheers.

Comment: Your solution is perfect for getting the direct link but if we were able to get the href attribute of **<a class="rg_l>** we could then click programmatically the "Search by image" button and get the image of the biggest size.

Comment: I've noticed that it gets only the first 100 found elements. How could I get the whole found elements?

Comment: See the update: using phantomJs I was able to get the href attribute and get more results. Cheers.

Comment: The page populates and extends while scrolling, that makes scraping a bit harder. The zoomfactor is a bit of a trick, forcing directly more "visible" results in the viewport. window.setInterval defines that we scroll every 500 ms, then check if we got more results than before and try to click the show more results button (with a threshold, to account for lazy loading).

Comment: Thank you very much! Since that the search url in the script is a const, I was thinking to re-write "page.js" through java (basically the same, changing only the search term) for every query made. P.S. Just for curiosity,  I've noticed that basically you load all the results by clicking the **smb** button and then save the page locally. But why did you get the **data-ri** attribute from the selected divs?

Comment: data-ri stores the index for the returned search results, I use that to check if the result set changes. I will update my answer in a couple of minutes with passing the search url as parameter to the script.

Comment: Yeah, while I was writing I realized that you did so to check if the last index was bigger than the previous divCount (meaning more results). Yes, thank you, I'll wait for the update. Anyway, let me tell you that your solution was great (especially the zoomfactor trick).

Comment: Done, check out the new update. You can now pass the url and the search-term to the script from the java code. The search-term is used to name the output file (in case you are going to do parallel queries, etc.). Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, indeed I'm going to do do parallel queries. Again, really nice work! Thank you.