# Java Jsoup Google Image Search result parsing

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using jsoup to parse Google image results. I'm trying to get the `src` of the image. Here is my code so far. The output is truncated for some reason and I can't access the `src` attribute. Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to fix it? Thanks so much!

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        // Does a google image search for "test"
        final Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/search?q=test&tbm=isch").userAgent(USER_AGENT).get();

        // selects images
        Elements elements = doc.select("img.rg_ic.rg_i");
            // cycles through elements and prints attributes
            for (Element e : elements) {
                System.out.print(e);
            }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<img class="rg_ic rg_i" data-sz="f" name="XWXPqrX1RFJiaM:" alt="Image result for test" jsaction="load:str.tbn" onload="google.aft&&google.aft(this)">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [href field missing when I get the page using jsoup or htmlunit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044648/href-field-missing-when-i-get-the-page-using-jsoup-or-htmlunit)

Comment: Try it in your browser with disabled JavaScript and you have the source of the problem. So jsoup allone can't do the job, in above answer I was able to extract the results using phantomJS.

Comment: Jsoup is a html parser without JavaScript support. In cases, where jsoup doesn't provide the expected output usually the website relies on JavaScript. Then you usually try different approaches: look at the background requests (might be an API call you could use), run maybe selected scripts in an engine like rhino or use a headless browser with JavaScript support (Java: HtmlUnit; PhantomJS, etc.).

Comment: @FredericKlein What is PhantomJS?

Comment: Jsoup only reads the static website as it comes from the server, but Javascript is processed on the client side, so usually in your browser, which has a JavaScript engine. The scripts change the website, fetch additional data, etc. These changes are lost to jsoup, so you need a tool which can handle JavaScript and renders the page more like an actual browser. The result (the complete html source) could then of course be parsed with jsoup. In the documentation section is an example with HtmlUnit combined with jsoup: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsoup/4632/parsing-javascript-generated

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. So basically what I'm doing is loading the page with HtmlUnit in order to read the JavaScript aspects of the page, and then parsing it with Jsoup? Do I have that correct? And should I use phantomJS or HtmlUnit?

Comment: If I remember correctly, HtmlUnit also failed to load the page completely, that's why I discarded the Java only approach and used PhantomJS. The logic is the same though, grab the fully rendered page with some tool, parse it comfortably with jsoup.

Comment: I don't think that the portion of code that I want is Javascript. It's just the src. Here's the html: 
<img class="rg_ic rg_i __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" data-sz="f" name="XWXPqrX1RFJiaM:" alt="Image result for test" jsaction="load:str.tbn" onload="google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9jAAAAAAAAAAAAH/9k=" style="width: 225px; height: 225px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: -15px;">

Comment: I'm really at a loss as to why it doesn't include the src. That's all I need from this in order to complete my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code provides the urls for the first 100 image results with jsoup. If you need all results you have to use a headless browser (I recommend [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044648/href-field-missing-when-i-get-the-page-using-jsoup-or-htmlunit) for usage).

The static html source has the image urls for the first 100 result solely stored in [JSON objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp). For parsing the scraped JSON objects, I used [JSON.simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/)

The JSON objects are contained in the `<div>` elements with class `rg_meta` and are in the following form:

```
{"st":"Uber","tu":"https:\/\/encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com\/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTSEUMluu1kigjR3JU40BYfaH0fQ6JW1vk9WScBiXr--lsMILf2","ru":"https:\/\/newsroom.uber.com\/uberkittens-are-back\/","tw":300,"pt":"UberKittens Delivers Kittens to Play or Stay","ou":"https:\/\/newsroom.uber.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/10\/HQ_uberkittens_blog_960x540_r1v1.jpg","ow":960,"cl":6,"isu":"newsroom.uber.com","rid":"vLA3QXY8xPE4PM","cr":3,"ity":"jpg","sc":1,"ct":15,"s":"Clear Your Calendars\u2014#UberKITTENS Are Back","th":168,"oh":540,"id":"qCR7qXt7VX38iM:","itg":false,"cb":15}
```

So for the url we need to extract the value for the key "ou".

**Example Code**

```
// can only grab first 100 results
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36";
String url = "https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&q=kittens&gws_rd=cr";

List<String> resultUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent).referrer("https://www.google.com/").get();

    Elements elements = doc.select("div.rg_meta");

    JSONObject jsonObject;
    for (Element element : elements) {
        if (element.childNodeSize() > 0) {
            jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(element.childNode(0).toString());
            resultUrls.add((String) jsonObject.get("ou"));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("number of results: " + resultUrls.size());

    for (String imageUrl : resultUrls) {
        System.out.println(imageUrl);
    }

} catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Output**

```
number of results: 100
https://newsroom.uber.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/HQ_uberkittens_blog_960x540_r1v1.jpg
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/562466745340817408/_nIu8KHX.jpeg
http://leecamp.net/wp-content/uploads/kitten-3.jpg 
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you briefly explain what a JSON object is exactly and why you need JSON.simple to get the information that I need? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @namarino What is JSON: w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp In the static html source the image urls are only accessible through the JSON objects, stored in the div elements with class rg_meta. Jsoup is a html parser, so the JSON structure is not parsable. Hence we need a JSON parser, like JSON.simple to parse the object and query the values (the urls) for specific keys ("ou").

Comment: Hey thanks so much, I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: this is not working maybe because there is no `rg_meta ` so I examine the page and tried with `img[class^=rg_]` , but it is still not working , can you guide me with this