# Jsoup: read out formular / send parameter / find mouseOnClick?

Tags: java, html, jsoup, html-parser

I'm trying to execute an url, that I have read out from the HTML-code, to extract data from this website. But when I call this site I get a `Null pointer exception`, cause there is an `agecheck` preventing me from calling the required site. How can I bypass this agecheck?

I think about finding the formulare in the HTML-Code and send a paramter for this button (it is expected that an human being ist clicking on that button to proof, that your age is older than 18). Is this possible to do that with Jsoup?

What I try to do in the whole thing is, to collect data from 11 thousands websites. First I get the linked url to each of those websites, than I'd like to call each site using a for-loop. And the problem is, that a few of those websites have an agecheck, so my for-loop brakes up throwing a `Null pointer exception`.

Would it be better to use something like "Mechanize", cause Jsoup only can parse HTML-Sites and I think I will run into more problems like that, where I have to fill out formulars or call up checklists?

Or can I do all this stuff with Jsoup too?

Comment: You will run into problems with jsoup because of the missing JavaScript support. I would go with PhantomJS to grab the pages, then parse them from file using jsoup.

Comment: I can grap all pages allready using Jsoup. Mainproblem is, to call this pages an bypass the agecheck. With PhantomJS you can do things like sending paramters for an submit-button?

Comment: Yes, PhantomJS can do, what you can do in the browser using JavaScript. You could also try HtmlUnit for a Java-only approach, but HtmlUnit is rather slow, for requesting a single cookie, it should be ok though.

Comment: I tried to run PhantomJS on Eclipse, but run into some problems (again...). I installed Nodeclipse PhantomJS in eclipse. But when I create a new PhantomJS Project, I can't find the folder Webcontent\Web-INF\lib, where I can put the Jsoup.jar. How can I run PhantomJS on Eclipse as a "dynamic Web Project"? With "HTMLUnit" I just can do that in the "normal" way.

Comment: I just trigger the script execution from java, never used it directly in eclipse. Compare: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39054195/1661938