# How to get JSON objects embedded in HTML page result of JS running by PhantomJS and pass them to java code?

Tags: javascript, java, json, phantomjs, parameter-passing

I use JS script code that described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044648/href-field-missing-when-i-get-the-page-using-jsoup-or-htmlunit), but I don't want to save html result page in html file. I want to extract Json object from `<div class="rg_meta">` and pass them to Java code.

In searching, I find using "document", but I get undefined error. I am newbie in PhantomJS and working with JSON in Java.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var system = require('system');

var url = "";
var searchParameter = "";
var count=0;

if (system.args.length === 4) {
    url=system.args[1];
    searchParameter=system.args[2];
    count=system.args[3];
}

if(url==="" || searchParameter===""){
    phantom.exit();
}

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';

page.zoomFactor = 0.1;

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1920,
  height: 1080
};

var divCount="-1";
var topPosition=0;
var unchangedCounter=0;


page.open(url, function(status) {
console.log("Status: " + status);
if(status === "success") {

    window.setInterval(function() {

        var newDivCount = page.evaluate(function() { 
            var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".rg_di.rg_bx.rg_el.ivg-i");
            return divs[divs.length-1].getAttribute("data-ri");
        });

        topPosition = topPosition + 1080;

        page.scrollPosition = {
            top: topPosition,
            left: 0
        };

        if(newDivCount===divCount){
            page.evaluate(function() {
                var elems=document.getElementByClassName("rg_meta");
                console.log(elems.length);
                var button = document.querySelector("#smb");
                if(!(typeof button === "undefined")) {
                    button.click();
                    console.log('Clicked');
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            });

            if(parseInt(unchangedCounter,10) === parseInt(count,10)){
               /* var path = searchParameter+'.html';
                fs.write('seedHtml/'+path, page.content, 'w');
                console.log('printing html');*/
                phantom.exit();
            }else{
                unchangedCounter=unchangedCounter+1;
            }
        }else{
            unchangedCounter=0;
        }
        divCount = newDivCount;

    }, 500);
}else{
    phantom.exit();
}
});
```

Comment: There is no function called `document.getElementByClassName`. It's actually `document. getElementsByClassName` (`Elements`, instead of `Element`). I think that is why you get `undefined` error. Can you try this?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does'n return error, it returns 0 result now.

Comment: Okay, now you can use `console.log(elems[0])` to print out it contents. Then you can consume that in Java code or somewhere else, I think.

Comment: You can use data attributes for div elements, please go to https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/  and have a look

Answer (score 0):

> HTML5 data Attributes

Fortunately, HTML5 introduces custom data attributes.

```
<div id="msglist" data-user="bob" data-list-size="5" data-maxage="180"></div>
```

Custom data attributes:

are strings — **you can store anything which can be string encoded, such as JSON**. **Type conversion must be handled in JavaScript.**
should only be used when no suitable HTML5 element or attribute exists.

> JavaScript Parsing #1:

Every browser will let you fetch and modify data- attributes using the **getAttribute** and **setAttribute** methods, e.g.

```
var msglist = document.getElementById("msglist");

var show = msglist.getAttribute("data-list-size");
msglist.setAttribute("data-list-size", show+3);
```

It works, but should only be used as a fallback for older browsers.

> JavaScript Parsing #2:

Since version 1.4.3, jQuery’s data() method has parsed HTML5 data attributes. You don’t need to specify the data- prefix so the equivalent code can be written:

```
var msglist = $("#msglist");

var show = msglist.data("list-size");
msglist.data("list-size", show+3);
```

Hope it helps!!!